# About devil's staircases

Tags: measure-theory, fractals

We say that a function $f:\left[a,b\right] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a *singular function* or a *devil's staircase* if $f$ satisfies the following properties:

1. $f$ is continuous;
2. $f(a) < f(b)$;
3. $f$ is non-decreasing on $\left[a,b\right]$;
4. There exists a set $N \subset \left[a,b\right]$ (named exceptional set) of Lebesgue measure $0$ such that for all $x \in \left[a,b\right] \setminus N$ the derivative of $f$ in $x$ exists and is zero.

Possibly, the most know example is the devil's staircase constructed such that the ternary Cantor set is its exceptional set. (http://math.mit.edu/~katrin/teach/18.100/Devil%27s-Staircase.pdf). In this case, the exceptional set satisfies that $\dim_H(\mathcal{E}) = 0$. There are also examples where the exceptional set has $\dim_H(\mathcal{E}) = 1$ (M. Urbanski, On the Hausdorff dimension of invariant sets for expanding maps of a circle. Ergodic Theory Dynam. Systems 6(2):295-309, 1986.)

1. Is it possible to construct a devil's staircase such that the exceptional set is countable?
2. Is it possible to construct a devil's staircase such that the exceptional set is uncountable and $\dim_H(\mathcal{E}) = 0$?
3. Are there any examples of similar functions to the devil's staircase such that the exceptional set is a Cantor set with positive Lebesgue measure?

Comment: The answer to 1 is no: a continuous function on [a,b] such that any of its Dini derivatives is non-negative up to a countable exceptional set is increasing. A reference is e.g. Dieudonné's Foundations of Modern Analysis.

Comment: For 2,3, or similar requirements on the shape of the exceptional set: recall that composing Cantor's $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with an increasing  homeo $\phi:[a,b]\to[0,1]$ you get a $f\circ \phi$ with exceptional set $N=\phi^{-1}(C)$...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check the reference that you mentioned and try the construction that you proposed. I haven't read nothing about Dini derivatives yet.

Answer (score 4):

From the comments by Pietro Majer.

For question 1: No, a continuous function on $[a,b]$ such that any of its [Dini derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative) is nonnegative up to a countable exceptional set is increasing (see [Dieudonné](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1406727911)).

For questions 2, 3, or similar requirements on the shape of the exceptional set: recall that composing Cantor's function $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with an increasing homeomorphism $\phi\colon[a,b]\to[0,1]$ you get a devil's staircase $f\circ \phi$ with exceptional set $N=\phi^{-1}(N)$.